# vimrc changes to not affect vim sessions, settings do not persist

Tags: vim, tabs, space

I'm trying to change my tabbing to 2-spaced width tabs instead of the default 4 spaced width.

My vimrc file looks like:

```
" Configuration file for vim
set modelines=0   " CVE-2007-2438
" Normally we use vim-extensions. If you want true vi-compatibility
" remove change the following statements
set expandtab
set backspace=2   " more powerful backspacing
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
map <C-c> "+y<CR>

" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "crontab -e"
au BufWrite /private/tmp/crontab.* set nowritebackup nobackup
" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "chpass"
au BufWrite /private/etc/pw.* set nowritebackup nobackup

let skip_defaults_vim=1
```

Even after I have changed the settings, my existing files are not 2-space tabbed.  If I add `:set expandtab` and `:set stoptab=2` to my files, it will permit 2 spaced tabbing for that session, but after I save, exit, and reopen the file, everything looks 4-spaced tabbed again.

Obviously I am not a vim expert.  How can I make it so that vim always uses 2 space tabs and that this setting persists across all sessions?

Answer (score 0):

If there were physical tabs inside your editing files, you could indeed change the visual appearance of the width of the tabs by changing the `'tabstop'` option value. Inside the text, the tabs would remain the same.

However, as you have `:set expandtab`, there shouldn't be any existing tabs inside your files (if they've been consistently edited), and any edits by you will insert the corresponding amount of *spaces* whenever you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. That leads to the behavior you're reporting: New edits will insert 2 spaces for every tab, but the existing lines will keep the indent of 4 spaces.

If you want to change the width of the indent when spaces are used, you have to physically change the number of spaces; e.g. reduce 4 spaces to 2. Vim offers the `:retab` command ([`:help change-tabs`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#change-tabs)), but its use with space-based indentation is cumbersome, and also it affects any whitespace, not just indent at the beginning of the line. It's easier to use `:substitute` for this. The following command halves the amount of spaces at the beginning of lines:

```
:%substitute/^\( \+\)\1/\1/e
```

**TL;DR**: With physical tabs inside the text, you can change the appearance via `'tabstop'` value, with physical spaces, you have to convert the number of spaces inside the text.